# Setting focus to kendo numeric textbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui

I am using the following code to create a kendo numeric textbox.

Html

```
<input type='text' name='num_wks_or_mons' id='num_wks_or_mons' tabindex='5'/>
```

Jquery

```
$("#num_wks_or_mons").width(295).kendoNumericTextBox({
            min:0,
            max:99,
            step:1,
            format: "n0"
        });
```

Evenif i am setting the `tabindex` attribute as 5 the element will not get the focus if if tabout from elemnent with `tabindex = 4`.When i tabout from element with `tabindex = 4` the focus is going to the next element which is not a kendo numeric textbox.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Set focus like this,

```
 $('#num_wks_or_mons').siblings('input:visible').focus();
```

Answer (score 1):

The Kendo UI Numeric Text Box widget has it's own focus method. Get the instance of the widget and call that.

```
var numerictextbox = $("#num_wks_or_mons").data("kendoNumericTextBox");
numerictextbox.focus();
```

https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/numerictextbox/methods/focus

Answer (score 1):

Try to this:

```
var $nodeNumeric = $nodeImput.kendoNumericTextBox().data("kendoNumericTextBox");
$($nodeNumeric._text).focus();
```

Answer (score 0):

Set focus like this,

```
   setTimeout("$('#num_wks_or_mons').focus();", 500);
```

Comment: I need to set the focus on the focusout of previous element.Not in a time interval

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
      setTimeout(function() {
          $('#txtThresholdAmount').siblings('input:visible').focus();
      }, 1000);
  });
</script>
```